# Problems installing SQL Server 2008 Express in Production

Tags: sql-server, godaddy, sql-server-2008

I'm having trouble setting up our external web server.

Since we have a pretty small audience, we got one cheap server and are using SQL Server Express for the database and ASP.NET for the application, all on one box.  (We are using GoDaddy for the hosting.)

Regardless of how bad these constraints are, this is where I'm stuck.

Everything is working OK, except that SQL Server will not successfully complete an install.  Originally I was using the Web Platform Installer for it, but it was trying to read the entire installer into memory to calculate the file hash.

Running the installer works almost all of the way to the end, which verifies to me that the server meets the minimum reqs to install.

GlobalRules:

```
AclPermissionsFacet           Passed
MediaPathLength               Passed
OsVersionCheck                Passed
RebootRequiredCheck           Passed
ThreadHasAdminPrivilegeCheck  Passed
WmiServiceStateCheck          Passed
```

InstallGlobalRules:

```
SSMS_IsInternetConnected         Not applicable    This rule does not apply to your system configuration.
AclPermissionsFacet              Passed
Bids2005InstalledCheck           Passed
BlockInstallSxS                  Passed
FacetDomainControllerCheck       Passed
FacetPowerShellCheck             Passed
FacetWOW64PlatformCheck          Passed
FusionRebootCheck                Passed
IsFirewallEnabled                Passed
PerfMonCounterNotCorruptedCheck  Passed
SqlUnsupportedProductBlocker     Passed
```

My most recent failure was "FixSqlRegistryKey_x86.exe - Application Error"

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Did you buy the server and put it in a GoDaddy rack or are you renting a server from them? I'm not sure of their policies but maybe they don't allow people to modify the registry on their servers. Perhaps one of their employees would have to work with you on this install if this is the case.

Are you able to make any manual changes to the registry?

Comment: Yeah, I was able to write to the registry.  I finally got it to install after stopping the MySQL service that I had started.  I think the server was under some severe memory pressure.